# A problem about relativistic particle actions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, geodesics, point-particles

I have a problem of a course in General Relativity which I don’t know to start solving, and I was wondering if someone could give me some indications or ideas on how to figure it out. It is the following:

In class we derived the geodesics equation from the action of a relativistic particle
$$
S_0=-m\int{d\lambda \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}}}$$
where $\lambda$ is a parameter along the particle trajectory $x^\mu(\lambda)$. In this problem, we will explore an alternative action that also holds in the limit $m\to 0$.

> 1. Consider the following action
>    $$S_1=\int d\lambda \frac{1}{2e(\lambda)} \Big[g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda} - m^2e^2(\lambda)\Big]$$
>    where $e(\lambda)$ (the einbein) is a new independent function.
>
> a) How does $e(\lambda)$ have to transform under $\lambda\to\lambda’$ in order for the action to be reparametrization invariant?
>
> b) Derive a constraint equation by varying the action $S_1$ with respect to $e(\lambda)$. Plugging this constraint back into $S_1$, show that the new action reduces to $S_0$.
>
> c) Now vary the action $S_2$ with respect to $x^{\mu}$. For which choices of the einbein does the resulting Euler-Lagrange equation reduce to the geodesic equation? Because the action is invariant under reparametrizations of $\lambda$, you can choose any non-zero value of $e(\lambda)$.

Thanks so much for your help, I found myself so lost with this problem that I didn’t even know how to start.

Comment: Hi @cut. Welcome to Phys.SE. The post (v2) seems _too broad._ Many of the subquestions have  already answers on Phys.SE.